# Where in Hue can I find status information emitted from a Hadoop Streaming process?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hue

I am trying to implement status updates as explained in [Hadoop Streaming documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#How+do+I+update+status+in+streaming+applications%3):

> *How do I update status in streaming applications?*
>   A streaming process can use the stderr to emit status information. To set a status, `reporter:status:<message>` should be sent to `stderr`.

Is this `reporter:status` information saved anywhere **or** is it only a heartbeat message to show that the Streaming process is in progress?

- If I call `sys.stderr.write("test message")`, I can go to *attempt > Logs > stderr* in Hue and see this message.
- However, if I change it to `sys.stderr.write("reporter:status:test message")`, I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you see it in the regular Hadoop UI? (as if you don't see it there too, it might be more how Hadoop works than a problem in Hue)

Comment: @Romain No, I don't, but I don't know where to look. Is it a status of a job, task, attempt?

Comment: It should be in the tasks/attempt but not familiar with Streaming anymore (was doing python UDF in Pig)